# Cannot load more than 2 files to S3 using plupload

Tags: amazon-s3, plupload

My code below works fine so long as I only load 2 multiple files. If I load 3 or more, every file after the 2nd one does not get added to my s3 bucket (although no error is shown by plupload).

Can anyone understand why?

```
     var uploader = new plupload.Uploader({
     browse_button: 'browse', // this can be an id of a DOM element or the DOM element itself
     url: 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/mybucket',
     filters: {
         max_file_size: '25mb',
         prevent_duplicates: true,
         multiple_queues: true
     }
 });

 uploader.init();

 uploader.bind('FilesAdded', function (up, files) {
     plupload.each(files, function (file) {

         var myFileName = file.name.toLowerCase();
         myFileName = myFileName.replace(/[|&;$%@"<>()+,]/g, "");

         var elem = $('#hfReplyGuid');


             $.ajax({
                 type: "POST",
                 contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                 dataType: "json",
                 url: "WebService.asmx/prepareUpload",
                 data: "{'acl':'private','bucket':'myBucket','file':'" + folderPath + elem.val() + "_" + myFileName + "'}",
                 success: function (data) {
                     params[myFileName] = { policy: data.d[0].Policy, signature: data.d[0].Signature };

                     var multipart_params = {
                         'key': folderPath + elem.val() + "_" + myFileName,
                         'filename': folderPath + elem.val() + "_" + myFileName,
                         'AWSAccessKeyId': AWSAccessKey,
                         'acl': 'private',
                         'signature': params[myFileName]["signature"],
                         'policy': params[myFileName]["policy"],
                         'success_action_status': '201'
                     }


                     up.setOption('multipart_params', multipart_params);

                     uploader.start();
                 },
                 error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                     alert(xhr.status);
                     alert(xhr.responseText);
                     alert(thrownError);
                 }
             });

     });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by basing code on this post [Upload multiple files to Amazon S3 using plupload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405440/upload-multiple-files-to-amazon-s3-using-plupload)

However I had to create the policies in the FileFiltered event, start the uploader in the FilesAdded event and then add each policy in the BeforeUpload event as below:

```
       var multipart_params = policies[file.id];
       up.setOption('multipart_params', multipart_params);
```